# Swisscom Developer Cloud: How to configure an SPF record?

Tags: spf, swisscomdev

Where would I point an SPF record? E-mails sent from my Node instance on the Swisscom Developer Cloud (through Hostpoint's SMPT) are currently treated as spam by many recipients. Setting an SPF record would probably improve the classification of an e-mail.

Is there a fixed IP I can use? Or an IP range?

Comment: please post the headers of a message treated as SPAM. Thanks.

Comment: SPF isn't a magic bullet. Adding SPF will only help if you're being marked as spam *because of* SPF absence or failures - received message headers should tell you if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I just stood for a similar problem ...

**Logic:**

You send emails from a Swisscom server.
You send the emails with a specific email address.

**Where?**

Where is the domain of this email address? There you have to create or complete an entry in the DNS.

**What?**

The Swisscom server has an IP address.
This must be added to the SPF1 entry.

**Instructions for Hostpoint**
https://support.hostpoint.ch/en/technical/e-mail/frequently-asked-questions/how-can-i-add-an-spf-record-for-my-domain

Example of the IP address "1.2.3.4"
v = spf1 ip4: 1.2.3.4 -all

No, you can not authorize foreign email addresses that are not yours.
No, you can not do that, for example Authorize GMail addresses.
If you can not edit the DNS zone of the email domain, you could use sending per SMTP.